# Splitting an IPv6 cidr into /64 blocks, in php

Tags: php, ipv6, cidr

I'm looking to create a script that will take an ipv6 range or cidr as input, and spit out a list of /64 blocks (or the first IP in each /64 block).

I have a function that does something similar for IPv4 IPs, but I lack the understanding to re-purpose it for ipv6.

```
Function BreakTo30($CIDR)
{
    $CIDR = explode("/", $CIDR); // this breaks the CIDR block into octlets and /notation
    $octet = ip2long($CIDR[0]); //turn the first 3 octets into a long for calculating later
    $NumberOf30s = pow(2,(30-$CIDR[1]))-1; //calculate the number of /30s in the CIDR block
    $OutputArray = array();
    for ($i=-4; $i<4 * $NumberOf30s; $OutputArray[] = (long2ip($octet + ($i += 4)))); //fancy math to output each /30
    return $OutputArray; //returns an array of ranges

}
```

ip2long and long2ip are ipv4 only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is this solution that matches your requirements and needs you to match its :D

Its requirement is to have GMP or BCMATH extensions installed, because in this case you will be dealing with very big decimals.

```
<?php
$cidr ="2001:adb8:85a3:1111:1111:8a2e:3270:7334/120";
$all = listIPv6InBlock($cidr);

echo "CIDR is $cidr<br/>\r\n";
echo "Count is ". count($all)."<br/>\r\n";

printAddresses($all);

function listIPv6InBlock($CIDR)
{
    $CIDR = explode("/", $CIDR); // this breaks the CIDR block into octlets and /notation
    $octet = ip2long_v6($CIDR[0]); //turn the first 3 octets into a long for calculating later
    $NumberOfIPs = pow(2,(128-$CIDR[1]))-1; //calculate the number of /30s in the CIDR block
    $OutputArray = array();
    for ($i=0; $i< $NumberOfIPs; $i++){
        $OutputArray[] = long2ip_v6(bcadd($octet,"$i"));
    }
    return $OutputArray; //returns an array of ranges
}

function printAddresses($arr){
    foreach($arr as $ip){
        echo "$ip <br/>\r\n";       
    }
}

/*
 *The following two functions are credited to (https://stackoverflow.com/users/67332/glavi%C4%87) 
 * who gave this answer :https://stackoverflow.com/a/19497446/896244
 */
function ip2long_v6($ip) {
    $ip_n = inet_pton($ip);
    $bin = '';
    for ($bit = strlen($ip_n) - 1; $bit >= 0; $bit--) {
        $bin = sprintf('%08b', ord($ip_n[$bit])) . $bin;
    }

    if (function_exists('gmp_init')) {
        return gmp_strval(gmp_init($bin, 2), 10);
    } elseif (function_exists('bcadd')) {
        $dec = '0';
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($bin); $i++) {
            $dec = bcmul($dec, '2', 0);
            $dec = bcadd($dec, $bin[$i], 0);
        }
        return $dec;
    } else {
        trigger_error('GMP or BCMATH extension not installed!', E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}

function long2ip_v6($dec) {
    if (function_exists('gmp_init')) {
        $bin = gmp_strval(gmp_init($dec, 10), 2);
    } elseif (function_exists('bcadd')) {
        $bin = '';
        do {
            $bin = bcmod($dec, '2') . $bin;
            $dec = bcdiv($dec, '2', 0);
        } while (bccomp($dec, '0'));
    } else {
        trigger_error('GMP or BCMATH extension not installed!', E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    $bin = str_pad($bin, 128, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $ip = array();
    for ($bit = 0; $bit <= 7; $bit++) {
        $bin_part = substr($bin, $bit * 16, 16);
        $ip[] = dechex(bindec($bin_part));
    }
    $ip = implode(':', $ip);
    return inet_ntop(inet_pton($ip));
}
?>
```

As you can see, this solution is performing calculations on decimals (as strings).

**Note 1**

The solution you provided as an example for IPv4 is listing every forth IP address in the block, the one that I provided is listing all the IP addresses in the block, you can adjust this by using `$i+=4` instead of `$i++`

**Note 2**

Why do we use GMP/BCMATH? The answer is that big decimals at some point will be converted into **floats** which will cause the numbers to lose precision, which is not good for this kind of calculations.

**Credits**

Thanks to **[Glavić](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67332/glavi%C4%87)** for posting this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19497446/896244) on how to convert IPv6 to decimals and vice versa

Comment: @Moist_Gerbil so when do I get the bounty?

Comment: Should be awarded by now.

Answer (score 0):

I looked this over again, and the accepted answer is not exactly what I wanted, as it lists /128 blocks, instead of /64. listIPv6InBlock needs to be changed to this:

```
function listIPv6InBlock($CIDR)
{
    $CIDR = explode("/", $CIDR); // this breaks the CIDR block into octlets and /notation
    $octet = ip2long_v6($CIDR[0]); 
    $NumberOfIPs = pow(2,(64-$CIDR[1])); //calculate the number of /64s in the CIDR block
    $OutputArray = array();
    $a = gmp_init($octet);
    $b = gmp_init('18446744073709551616'); // long /64

    for ($i=0; $i< $NumberOfIPs; $i++){
        $c = gmp_mul($b,$i);
        $d = gmp_add($a,$c);

        $OutputArray[] = long2ip_v6(gmp_strval($d));
    }
    return $OutputArray; //returns an array of ranges
}
```